# Sort array of ranges ['55-66', '>55', '<66']?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, typescript, range

Example input:

```
[ '50-59', '60-69', '40-49', '>=70', '<40' ]
```

Expected output

```
[ '<40', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '>=70' ]
```

Attempt; expanded from my previous one-liner (for debugging):

```
export function sort_ranges(ranges: string[]): string[] {
    const collator = new Intl.Collator(undefined, {
        numeric: true,
        sensitivity: 'base',
        ignorePunctuation: true
    });
    return ranges.sort((a: string, b: string): number => {
            const bNaN: boolean = !isNaN(parseInt(b[0]));
            const col = () =>
                console.info(`collator(${a}, ${b}) = ${collator.compare(a, b)}`
                            ) || collator.compare(a, b);
            if (a[0] === '<' && bNaN) {
                console.info('< =', a);
                return -1;
            }
            else if (a[0] === '>' || b[0] === '>') {
                console.info('> =', a);
                return 1;
            }
            else return col();
        }
    );
}
```

[Runnable (mocha+chai in a plnkr)](https://plnkr.co/edit/eNJrSaFKjVNrbqE4gtxe?p=preview)

Note: ranges are guaranteed to be non-overlapping, and there may be other things in the array like 'foo' which should be put in whatever order at the end of the array.

Ideas: I could build a new array like `[[50,59], ['<', '40']]` then try overriding the `.sort` method again, but that seems crazy. Is there a better solution?

Comment: I don't get why is the `60-69` and `50-59` before `40-49` in the expected result.

Comment: Whoops, my bad; copied it over in a rush

Comment: Where would 51-57 go?

Comment: Ranges are guaranteed to be non-overlapping

Comment: James: `parseInt` does that, but when I had other things in the array that were `NaN` I had issues. Which is why the `isNaN` code originally appears. Also what mplungjan said about <40, 40-49

Comment: @JamesThorpe ` '<40', '40-49'` does need to be in that order

Comment: @mplungjan Ah, true - I missed that

Comment: Does the code not work? You forgot to tell us that...

Comment: @mplungjan - Yeah I had it on 1 line previously, unrolled it for debugging.  I get some weird output like `> = 60-69`. Yeah the code doesn't work for all inputs, which is why I said "Attempt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the other answers didn't handle edge cases. As an added bonus, no regex:

```js
function sort_ranges(ranges/*: string[]*/)/*: string[]*/ {
    return ranges.sort((a/*: string*/, b/*: string*/)/*: number*/ => {
        if (a[0] === '<') return -1;
        else if (a[0] === '>') return a[0].charCodeAt() - b[0].charCodeAt();
        else if (isNaN(parseInt(a[0])) || b[0] === '<') return 1;
        else if (b[0] === '>' || isNaN(parseInt(b[0]))) return -1;
        return parseInt(a.split('-')[0]) - parseInt(b.split('-')[0])
    });
}

// Test code for StackOverflow:

const expected_arrays = Object.freeze([
    [ '<40', '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '>=70' ],
    [ '40-49', '50-59', '60-69', '>=70', 'all' ]
]);

const input_arrays = Object.freeze([
    [ '60-69', '<40', '>=70', '50-59', '40-49' ],
    [ '50-59', 'all', '40-49', '>=70', '60-69' ]
]);

for(let i=0; i<input_arrays.length; i++)
    console.info(sort_ranges(input_arrays[i]), '===', expected_arrays[i]);
```

Answer (score 7):

```js
var a = [ '50-59', '60-69', '40-49', '>=70', '<40' ];

a.sort(function(a,b) {
  if (a[0] === '<') return -1;
  if (a[0] === '>') return 1;
  if (b[0] === '<') return 1;
  if (b[0] === '>') return -1;
  return a.match(/\d+/)[0] - b.match(/\d+/)[0];
});

console.dir( a );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could match numbers and if two numbers are available, take it for an adjusted sort.

```js
var array = ['50-59', '60-69', '40-49', '>=70', '<40', 'all'];

array.sort(function (a, b) {
    function getV(v) { return v.match(/\d+/g) || [Infinity, Infinity]; }
    var aa = getV(a),
        bb = getV(b);

    return aa[0] - bb[0] || (aa[1] || aa[0]) - (bb[1] || bb[0]);
});

console.log(array)
```

Comment: What if any of the elements in your `return` are null?

Comment: you could add a default value, like `return (aa[0] || 0) - (bb[0] || 0) || (aa[1] || aa[0] || 0) - (bb[1] || bb[0] || 0);`

Comment: `TypeError: bb is null`. PS: See my answer for a working model